# Second CSS does not link/apply

Tags: html, css

I am testing my codes parallel to a video tutorial. I have two CSS files. First one is working fine. Second CSS doesn't seems to apply to the HTML. My folder structure is as follows.

- /

  - css (screen_style.css, screen_layout_large.css)
  - images (banner_large.jpg, logo_large.png, etc)
  - index.html

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <title>Lynda.com | Creating a Responsive Web Design</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_layout_large.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <header>
                <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
            </header>

            <article>
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <a href="#">Duis aute irure</a> dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </article>

            <div class="promo_container">
                <div class="promo one">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                        <p><a class="cta" href="">Visit our blog</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="promo two">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit est laborum.</p>
                        <p><a class="cta" href="">Read the article</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="promo three">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor inci did unt.</p>
                        <p><a class="cta" href="">Learn more</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <nav>
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </nav>

            <footer>
                &copy; AG IT Solutions.
            </footer>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS/screen_tyle**

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Global Content Formatting and Styles */

body {
    color: #575c7a;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background:#515673 url(../images/background_gradient.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
}

.page {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #a6430a;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}

h2 { font-size: 1.7em; margin: 0 0 1em 0;}

h3 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 0 0 1em 0;}

p { margin:0 0 0.75em 0;}

a { color:#de9000;}

a:hover {color:#009eff;}

a.cta { 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:.9em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: .5em 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 12px 0 0;
    background: url(../images/cta_arrow.png) no-repeat right 0;
}

a.cta:hover {
    background-position:right -50px;
}

.promo h3 {font-size: 1.1em; margin:0;}

.promo p {line-height:1.2em; font-size:.9em; margin-bottom:.5em;}

.promo { background-repeat: no-repeat;}

.promo.one { background-image: url(../images/promo_1.jpg);}
.promo.two { background-image: url(../images/promo_2.jpg);}
.promo.three { background-image: url(../images/promo_3.jpg);}

footer { 
    font-size: .85em; 
    color: #9ba0bd;
    background-color:#575c7a;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

**css/screen_layout_large**

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Layout (global rules for all sizes) */

body {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

header a.logo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Layout Large Screens (default for older browsers) */

header {
    height: 275px;
    background: url(../images/banner_large.jpg) no-repeat right 0;
}

header a.logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 85px;
    top: 28px;
    right: 30px;
    background-image: url(../images/logo_large.png);
}
```

None of the images are loading in header section which are scripted in screen_layout_large.css. Padding also not working. I have tried including !important with css attributes. But problem seems to be the CSS is not linking. When I remove the first CSS, it has only plain HTML.

Comment: Well, removing the first one will not really do much, as the rules in the second one isn't really changing how anything looks. What you should do is look in Firebug or similar ("inspect element") in a browser, and see what rules are applied to each element, and if the backgrounds are loaded, look to see if the links work.

Comment: Did you try to open css links in your devtools to be sure, that both css files are connected?

Comment: Right click on  your page, and select "view source" (or similar, depending on browser). When the source code opens on a new tab, click (or right-click-open in new tab) the link to the second CSS. Does it open?

Comment: I checked it with Firefox, and both css are working fine. But in Chrome, second css doesn't seem to work

Comment: @coopersita: In Chrome page source, when I click on the second css link, the css has only the comments. None of the rules that I have added is there

Comment: `@charset "UTF-8";

/* Layout (global rules for all sizes) */

/* Layout Large Screens (default for older browsers) */`

Answer (score 0):

Try to open your developer tools (**F12** for google chrome) and inside `head` element find your two `links` to css files. **Mouse2** **->** **Open link in new tab**

[image]

If both files **will not be empty** (you should see any your css properties), let us to know. **If one of them is empty**, it means that you didn't connect it correctly.

Comment: Second one is empty (only comments are there). But works well in firefox. It shows the CSS when I clicked on the link at page source. Is there a fix for Chrome? But chrome support most of the CSS3/HTML5 stuff, right?

Comment: @akalanka, chrome supports much more than other browsers. It's a little strange

Comment: @akalanka, if your project is small, try to create new project with the same structure and be sure, that all you CSS files are connected (using devtools). If it will be OK, just copy-paste all your content, may be the issue is simply misprint somewhere, because your code looks OK.

Comment: Strange thing is same code works in firefox, not in chrome. My code is running in apache server in wamp

Comment: By the way project is a small one...I just went through dev-tools.. second css is empty except for the charset and comments..

Comment: @akalanka, try just to remove `@charset "UTF-8";` from your css files. I have no idea what happens. My last thought is that problem somewhere in the `meta`, may be `charset`.

Comment: It was a cash issue in Chrome.. I clear browser cash and file cash...Even restart the machine... Now it's working..How ironic

Comment: @akalanka pretty simple, but hard to guess)

Answer (score 0):

Clear browser cash was the solution at this particular issue...